# How to redirect a page with an additional URL variable

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, parameters

I'd like to redirect a single page (index.php) from an old location (http://old.com) to a new location (http://new.com). This page can have various URL parameters, and I need to add an additional parameter (for example: p=9). The redirection should also work when index.php is not specified, since it's the default file.

A few examples of the desired results:

```
http://old.com                       -> http://new.com/index.php?p=9
http://old.com/                      -> http://new.com/index.php?p=9
http://old.com/index.php             -> http://new.com/index.php?p=9
http://old.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3 -> http://new.com/index.php?a=1&b=2&c=3&p=9
http://old.com/index.php?p=555       -> not important, parameter p can't be there
```

After research on the net and various tests, this is my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/index.php(.*)$ http://new.com/index.php?p=9 [R=301,L,QSA]
```

Unfortunately it doesn't merge the existing parameters with the new one, as I'd expect. Nor does it work when index.php is not specified.